# Aligning 2 <ul> blocks in an angular template

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I would like to align two ul blocks.  Currently I have them rendering next to each other but they are lined up from the bottom, not from the top:

```
<div class="ingredients-container">
  <div style="display: inline-block; width: 15em">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="...">
       {{ ... }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div style="display: inline-block; width: 15em">
   <ul>
     <li ng-repeat="...">
       {{ ... }}
     </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

The first li item in the right hand side ul block is not rendering in line with the first li item on the left hand side.  It appears that the li items are rather being aligned from the bottom of the container div instead.  How do I reverse this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the `display: inline-block` wrapper elements specify `vertical-align: top` to have them line up